# Can conditionals be used inside the then block of a FEEL/Literal expression in dmn

Tags: kie, dmn, feel-language

We are using Literal Expressions for one of our decisions.

Would like to see if coinditionals is supported inside the then ?

Returns with an invalid dmn

if(somecondition)  then {
**if(newcondition) then {....} else {}**

}else if (another condition) then {}

else {}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, conditionals *can* be used inside the then block of a FEEL/Literal expression in DMN.

The problem you are experiencing is that `{ }` in FEEL is used to denote a context, while you possibly wanted to use `()` to parenthesise part of your expression.

In other words, you expression should be ~like:

```
if somecondition
then ( if (newcondition) then ... else ... )
else ( if (another condition) then ... else ... )
```

For example:

```
if a number > 0
then ( if modulo(a number, 2) = 0 then "pos even" else "pos odd" )
else "neg"
```

Demo:

[image: demo nested conditional in DMN FEEL expression]